# django: handler404 and TemplateView.as_view

Tags: python, django

I want to optimize my code:

```
# --- views.py ---
def error_page_404(request):
    return render(request, '404.html', status=404)


# --- urls.py ---
handler404 = 'main.views.error_page_404'

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ...
    url(r'^404$', 'main.views.error_page_404'),
    # ...
)
```

New my code:

```
# --- urls.py ---
handler404 = TemplateView.as_view(template_name="404.html", status_code=404)
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ...
    url(r'^404$', handler404),
    # ...
)
```

Advantages of new code is we will not need views in views.py (for 404, 403, 500 templates).
Unfortunately, this code doesn't work for me.
I get error:

```
    TemplateView() received an invalid keyword 'status_code'. as_view only accepts arguments that are already attributes of the class
```

If use "status" instead then it is error too. 
How is correct? Anybody help me? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any custom views for this task.  Use the django's built-in:

```
url(r'^404/$', 'django.views.defaults.page_not_found'),
```

Comment: Thank you. I used 
`handler404 = 'django.views.defaults.page_not_found' 
urlpatterns = patterns('', ... url(r'^404$', handler404),)` 
- it is work!